# setting css style from controller angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I've been at this for 30 minutes and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong...

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="main">
    <div ng-style="mapheight">
        <google-map center="center" zoom="zoom" style="height: inherit;"></google-map>
        </div>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
angular.module('csApp.controllers', ["google-maps"]).
    controller("main", function($scope) {
        $scope.mapheight = "{'min-height':" + getHeight() + "px;}";
        $scope.center = {
            latitude: 45,
            longitude: -73
        };
        $scope.zoom = 8;

        function getHeight() {
            return (window.innerHeight * .70);
        }
    })
```

No style is being applied to my div at all.

I can get it pass the variable when I put {{mapheight}} in my template but then I have to pass it to the style property, which is apparently not how I should do it.

What am I doing wrong here?  This is my first day with angular and I'm almost in tears because I can't even resize a div.

Thank you!

here is the change in my controller:

```
  $scope.mapHeight = { 'min-height': getHeight() };
```

Comment: There is always a "first day", that does not mean shedding tears would help. :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`ng-style` takes an object binding, so `$scope.mapheight` should be an object rather than a string. i.e.

```
$scope.mapheight = {
    'min-height': getHeight() + "px"
};
```

The `ng-style` attribute takes an expression, so putting the string version directly in the HTML

```
ng-style="{'min-height': '40px'}"
```

would work as it would be evaluated and an object would be created. Setting `ng-style="mapheight"` is evaluated as taking the value of `mapheight` from `$scope` so `$scope.mapheight` needs to be an object.

Comment: Thank you so much!  It's be so incredibly frustrating to go from being able to put together web-apps in a few hours to not being able to resize a div!  Thanks.  I will post the working code!

Comment: You're welcome, and don't worry. Once you get your head around it all, it's a brilliant framework to work with.